# Is there a way to modify the cluster resources allocated futures when using a furrr function?

Tags: r, r-future, furrr

I'm using the **future**, **future.batchtools** and **furrr** packages within my R script, in order to run code on a **slurm**-managed remote machine.

When I define my future topology, I pass a template file to `future.bacthtools::batchtools_slurm()` and define the computational resources for the slurm jobs with the `resources =` argument.

When I then run the `furrr::future_pwalk()` function, every future is evaluated with the same resources, namely the ones that I defined in `batchtools_slurm()`.

Is there a way to have the jobs use different resources, depending on a variable passed to `furrr::future_pwalk()`?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak future resources before hand

```r
library(future)
library("future.batchtools")
library(furrr)

slurm <- future::tweak(batchtools_slurm,
                       template = "slurm_batchtools.tmpl",
                       resources=list(
                         cores = 4
                       )
plan(slurm)
```

The slurm_batchtools.tmpl file being

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=<%= job.name %>
#SBATCH --output=<%= log.file %>
#SBATCH --error=<%= log.file %>
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=<%= resources[["cores"]] %>
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=10000

<%= if (array.jobs) sprintf("#SBATCH --array=1-%i", nrow(jobs)) else "" %>
Rscript -e 'batchtools::doJobCollection("<%= uri %>")'
```